# RuntimeError: Given transposed=1, weight of size [64, 1, 4], expected input[2, 128, 74] to have 64 channels, but got 128 channels instead > unet error

Tags: pytorch, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, torch, torchvision

I’m trying to implement very very simple UNET from this code.

```py
class unet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, ngf=64, norm_layer=nn.BatchNorm1d):
        super(unet, self).__init__()

        # construct unet structure
        unet_block = skipconnection_block(ngf*2, ngf, submodule=None, norm_layer=norm_layer, inner=True)
        unet_block = skipconnection_block(ngf, 1, submodule=unet_block, norm_layer=norm_layer, outer=True)
        self.model = unet_block

    def forward(self, x):
        self.unet = nn.Sequential(self.model)
        x = self.unet(x)
        return x


class skipconnection_block(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, inner_nc, outer_nc, submodule=None, outer=False, inner=False, norm_layer=nn.BatchNorm1d):
        super(skipconnection_block, self).__init__()
        self.outer = outer

        downrelu = nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, True)
        uprelu = nn.ReLU(True)

        if inner:
            downconv_0 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=outer_nc, out_channels=inner_nc, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=0)
            upconv_0 = nn.ConvTranspose1d(in_channels=inner_nc, out_channels=outer_nc, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=0)
            down = [downrelu, downconv_0]
            up = [uprelu, upconv_0, norm_layer(outer_nc)]
            model = down + up

        elif outer:
            downconv_1 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=outer_nc, out_channels=inner_nc, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=0)
            upconv_1 = nn.ConvTranspose1d(in_channels=inner_nc, out_channels=outer_nc, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=0)
            down = [downrelu, downconv_1, norm_layer(inner_nc)]
            up = [uprelu, upconv_1, norm_layer(outer_nc)]
            model = down + [submodule] + up

        self.model = nn.Sequential(*model)

    def forward(self, x):
        if self.outer:
            return self.model(x)
        else:
            return torch.cat([x, self.model(x)], 1)
```

and when i tried like this for checking summary architecture of unet,

```py
    unet = load_skip_model()
    device = torch.device('cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
    unet.to(device)
    print(torchsummary.summary(unet, (1, 150)))
```

i got this result below.

```py
RuntimeError: Given transposed=1, weight of size [64, 1, 4], expected input[2, 128, 74] to have 64 channels, but got 128 channels instead
```

I dont understand why i got this.
can anyone please please give some help…?? thank uu

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, when you define a neural network like so, first check your layer in/out dims one by one.

Here for example, your first conv1d does not receive the expected dimension as input which cause you error.